# Difference between cofinal map and cofinal

Tags: terminology, order-theory

In this [note](http://thales.doa.fmph.uniba.sk/sleziak/texty/rozne/topo/subnets2.pdf) I read, the cofinal map is defined as,

> Let $\mathbb D´$ and $\mathbb D$ be two directed sets, $f: \mathbb D´ \to \mathbb D$ is a cofinal map, if $M$ is cofinal in $\mathbb D´$, then $f[M]$ is cofinal in $\mathbb D$.

What´s the difference between the aformentioned definition with merely defining as $f[\mathbb D´]$ is
cofinal in $\mathbb D$?

I think they´re supposed to be different, but it seems to me the second, the weaker one, implies the first.

Comment: It only does that if $f$ is assumed to be an order homomorphism.

Comment: Note that $\mathbb{D}'$ is cofinal in itself, so it certainly implies having a cofinal image.

Comment: If I understand it correctly, according to wikipedia, [here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cofinal_(mathematics)#Related_Notions), the second definition is called final (and not cofinal).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The two definitions are not equivalent. E.g., take $\mathbb{D}' = \mathbb{D} = \mathbb{N}$ with the usual ordering and define $f(n)$ to be $n$ if $n$ is even and to be $0$ if $n$ is odd. Then $f[\mathbb{D}]$ comprises the even numbers and is cofinal (so $f$ satisfies your proposed simpler definition). However, the set $O$ of odd numbers is cofinal, but $f[O] = \{0\}$ is not (so $f$ does not satisfy the definition you quoted from the note).